# getopt does not handle errors correctly

Tags: c, getopt

Hi I want to use `getopt` in my program. It works so far for a correct input, but when I use the synopsis the wrong way it prints: `option requires an argument -- 's'` after that I get a segmentation fault:

```
while((args = getopt(argc, argv, "ehs:")) != -1){
    switch (args) {
        case 'e':
            if (options.opts[0] == 1)
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
            else
                options.opts[0] = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
            if (options.opts[1] == 1)
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
            else
                options.opts[1] = 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            if (options.opts[2] == 2)
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
            else
                options.opts[2] = 2;
            char *saveptr;
            if((options.word = strtok_r(optarg, ":", &saveptr)) == NULL)
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "WORD MISSING");
            if((options.tag  = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr)) == NULL)
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "TAG MISSING");
            char *temp = NULL;
            if((temp = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr)))
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "WORD and TAG already set!");
            break;
        case '?': //Never enters this case or default. WHY???
        default:
            error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "");
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Here is my Opt struct if needed:

```
typedef struct Opt
{
    int opts[3];    //   e       h      s
    char *word,
         *tag;
} Opt;
```

Comment: I know that getopt gives you  the flag `?` for free, its part of the framework, the same goes for `--help`. you do not need to add these

Comment: @Karl ok but unfortunately  that does not change my problem

Comment: when outputing the error messages to the user, the user needs to be informed of the error.  a blanked statement like 'option multiple times' does not tell the user the specific problem.  perhaps using something similar to: 'option e can only occur once in the list of parameters

Comment: when using `error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "")` it just prints the synopsis

Comment: this seems to be what your trying to make use of:

    "If getopt() does not recognize an option character, it prints an
       error message to stderr, stores the character in optopt, and returns
       '?'.  The calling program may prevent the error message by setting
       opterr to 0."

Comment: @user3629249 now its there

Comment: @user3025417: I cannot reproduce this problem. Invoking with `-s` without an argument correctly triggers the `case '?'` code. Please verify that the code you pasted into the question is precisely the code you are testing, and/or provide the actual call which produces the error.

Comment: @rici interesting it is a 1:1 copy of my code

Comment: @user3025417: What does your `error_exit` do? Does it call exit()?

Answer (score 3):

Please learn how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or 
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Like [user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019507/15168), I created a test program based on what you showed, and cannot find the problem.

#### Test code (`goc.c`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Opt
{
    int opts[3];    //   e       h      s
    char *word,
         *tag;
} Opt;

enum E_Numbers { USAGE_ERROR };

static void error_exit(enum E_Numbers e, const char *tag)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", e, tag);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Opt options = { { 0 }, 0, 0 };
    int args;
    while((args = getopt(argc, argv, "ehs:")) != -1){
        switch (args) {
            case 'e':
                if (options.opts[0] == 1)
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
                else
                    options.opts[0] = 1;
                break;
            case 'h':
                if (options.opts[1] == 1)
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
                else
                    options.opts[1] = 1;
                break;
            case 's':
                if (options.opts[2] == 2)
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "option multiple times");
                else
                    options.opts[2] = 2;
                char *saveptr;
                if((options.word = strtok_r(optarg, ":", &saveptr)) == NULL)
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "WORD MISSING");
                if((options.tag  = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr)) == NULL)
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "TAG MISSING");
                char *temp = NULL;
                if((temp = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr)))
                    error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "WORD and TAG already set!");
                break;
            case '?': //Never enters this case or default. WHY???
            default:
                error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "Unexpected option");
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("e = %d, h = %d, s = %d\n", options.opts[0], options.opts[1], options.opts[2]);
    printf("word = <<%s>>\n", options.word ? options.word : "NULL");
    printf("tag  = <<%s>>\n", options.tag  ? options.tag  : "NULL");

    return 0;
}
```

The only change made in the body of the loop was to add the message `"Unexpected option"` to the call to `error_exit()` in the `default:` (and `case '?':`) code.

#### Example runs

```
$ ./goc
e = 0, h = 0, s = 0
word = <<NULL>>
tag  = <<NULL>>
$ ./goc -h -e
e = 1, h = 1, s = 0
word = <<NULL>>
tag  = <<NULL>>
$ ./goc -h -e -s abc:def
e = 1, h = 1, s = 2
word = <<abc>>
tag  = <<def>>
$ ./goc -h -e -s abc
0: TAG MISSING
$ ./goc -h -e -s abc:def:
e = 1, h = 1, s = 2
word = <<abc>>
tag  = <<def>>
$ ./goc -h -e -s abc:def:ghi
0: WORD and TAG already set!
$ ./goc -h -f -s abc:def:ghi
$ ./goc: illegal option -- f
0: Unexpected option
$ ./goc -a -b -c -d -e -f -h -e
./goc: illegal option -- a
0: Unexpected option
$ ./goc -s
./goc: option requires an argument -- s
0: Unexpected option
$ ./goc -s --
0: TAG MISSING
$ ./goc -s --:--
e = 0, h = 0, s = 2
word = <<-->>
tag  = <<-->>
$ ./goc -s --           # Note this one!
0: TAG MISSING
$ ./goc -s --:
0: TAG MISSING
$ ./goc -s --:--
e = 0, h = 0, s = 2
word = <<-->>
tag  = <<-->>
$ ./goc -s --::--
e = 0, h = 0, s = 2
word = <<-->>
tag  = <<-->>
$ ./goc -s --::--::
e = 0, h = 0, s = 2
word = <<-->>
tag  = <<-->>
$ ./goc -s --::--::--
0: WORD and TAG already set!
$
```

Because the `error_exit()` function actually exits, I don't get multiple errors reported from a single run; the first one is fatal.

No crashes; no unexpected behaviour.  I think your trouble is elsewhere.

For the record, testing was performed on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with GCC 5.1.0 and the standard `getopt()` provided by Apple on the platform.  However, I would expect the same behaviour on Linux too, and all the Unix platforms that I've worked on.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code I used for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int options[6] = {0};
    int args;

    while((args = getopt(argc, argv, "ehs:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (args)
        {
            case 'e':
                if (options[0] == 1)
                    printf( "option 'e' can only be included once \n" );
                else
                    options[0] = 1;
                break;

            case 'h':
                if (options[1] == 1)
                    printf( "option 'h' can only be included once\n" );
                else
                    options[1] = 1;
                break;

            case 's':
                if (options[2] == 2)
                    printf( "option 's' can only be included once\n" );
                else
                    options[2] = 2;
                break;

            case '?': //Never enters this case or default. WHY???
            default:
                printf( "unknown option encountered\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the command line I used: (untitled is the name of the test function)

```
./untitled -a -b -c -d -e -f -h -e
```

here is the result of the run.

```
./untitled: invalid option -- 'a'
unknown option encountered
./untitled: invalid option -- 'b'
unknown option encountered
./untitled: invalid option -- 'c'
unknown option encountered
./untitled: invalid option -- 'd'
unknown option encountered
./untitled: invalid option -- 'f'
unknown option encountered
option 'e' can only be included once
```

Since the test worked perfectly, I suspect the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

A single `:` in the option string means that the option requires an agument, which is either the rest of the argument after the character, or the next argument, if the option character is alone.  In this latter case `optarg` is set to the next pointer from the argument list, which will be NULL if there is no next argument.

So after seeing a bogus `-s` option, `getopt` will return `s`, and then your code will dereference `optarg`, which is a NULL pointer, causing a segfault (actually it passes it to `strtok_r`, which then proceeds to deref the uninitialized `save`, causing the same problem).  Check `optarg` to make sure it is not NULL in your `s` option code.

Comment: If the option argument is missing, getopt returns '?' (or ':' if the first character of the arg string parameter is ':').

Comment: @rici -- depends on the verison of `getopt` you are using.  POSIX doesn't define what happens when an argument that requires an argument is present but the argument isn't, so some (most?) versions return that option with NULL as the argument.

Comment: Posix: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html#tag_16_206_04  Seems pretty specific to me. Of course, older standards did not specify so clearly, but strtok_r is not in older posix standards either.

Comment: I've tried: `if(optarg == NULL) error_exit(USAGE_ERROR, "");` before using optarg but that doesn't work too.

Comment: Which versions on which platforms do that, Chris?  It isn't a behaviour I've seen.

Comment: Incidentally, the modern behaviour is mandated by POSIX 1997 for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/getopt.html): _If getopt() encounters an option character that is not contained in optstring, it returns the question-mark (?) character. If it detects a missing option-argument, it returns the colon character (:) if the first character of optstring was a colon, or a question-mark character (?) otherwise. In either case, getopt() will set the variable optopt to the option character that caused the error._